# In what manner are the functions called in this C++ code?

Tags: c++, function

I got this code from the c++ primer book, which was meant to explain the delete operator. However, what I don't understand is how the program calls the two functions and how they interact.

```
// delete.cpp -- using the delete operator
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring> // or string.h
using namespace std;
char * getname(void); // function prototype

int main()
{
    char * name; // create pointer but no storage

    name = getname(); // assign address of string to name
    cout << name << " at " << (int *) name << "\n";
    delete [] name; // memory freed

    name = getname(); // reuse freed memory
    cout << name << " at " << (int *) name << "\n";
    delete [] name; // memory freed again

    return 0;
}

char * getname() // return pointer to new string
{
    char temp[80]; // temporary storage
    cout << "Enter last name: ";
    cin >> temp;

    char * pn = new char[strlen(temp) + 1];
    strcpy(pn, temp); // copy string into smaller space

    return pn; // temp lost when function ends
}
```

The book provided the following sample run:

```
Enter last name: Fredeldumpkin
Fredeldumpkin at 0x004326b8
Enter last name: Pook
Pook at 0x004301c8
```

What I don't understand is how and why "Enter last name: " was executed twice, why the char * getname() function was executed before int main(), and how the two functions interact with each other.

Comment: What a horrid program. What book are you using?

Comment: You aren't reading one of those amateurish incomplete wiki-books are you?

Comment: `main` is calling `getname` twice, which is why "Enter last name" is showing twice.

Comment: yep it does look you started with the wrong foot learning C++, buy something good or look for quality free material: http://mindview.net/Books/TICPP/ThinkingInCPP2e.html/

Comment: @ the 1st two commentors: Addison Wesley's C++ Primer Plus 6th edition. Also, yes the code is ridiculously extravagant. Moreover, the book is, regrettably, amateurish.                                 @ Giovanni Azua: I'll go on an ebay spree later and add a better book to my list (of course, I'll research what books are good and bad). Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Enter last name" was printed twice because it gets printed in `getname()` and `getname()` is called twice.

`getname()` is *not* executed before `int main()`, it is declared. It must be declared so that when the compiler is compiling `main()` (which uses `getname()`), the compiler knows what is to be done.

`main()` is the first piece of executable code (that a developer normally has influence over, but there are exceptions). Everything that happens in your program is because either `main()` does it, or something `main()` calls (directly or indirectly) does it. In your sample, `main()` will: do the following:

1. call getname()
2. print something based on the return of getname()
3. release resources that were allocated inside getname()
4. call getname()
5. print something based on the return of getname()
6. release resources that were allocated inside getname()

Comment: "*return*" is an odd choice of word, because of its other meaning in C++. "de-allocate" or "destory" maybe?

Comment: So, I guess it's like the def name(): system in Python. It's odd that you declare getname() after int main(), and if you do otherwise you get warnings from the compiler though. Anyway, thanks for the explanation! I had thought that they were separate functions. getname() being a constituent of int main() makes much more sense.

Comment: @ThroatOfWinter57 - `getname()` is **declared** before `main`, on the line marked "function prototype". It is **defined** after `main`. Some folks like to write code this way, so that you get the overview in main before you dig into the details of `getname()`. Other folks (including me) do it the other way around, putting the definition of `getname()` before `main`, and removing the prototype, which is not needed if the definition comes first. And they are separate functions. `getname()` is called from `main()`, but it is not part of it.

Comment: @ Pete Becker - That's nice to hear, I'll use your latter method in the future; the former is odd to me.